# React: Props passed on to child class not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the `Parent` class below, `this.state.foo` works as expected, however in the `Child` class, `this.props.foo` is undefined.

This is a common issue, however none of the solutions that i've tried from other threads have worked.

React -v: 16.3

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      foo: 'test'
     };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">{this.state.foo}</h1>
        </header>
      <Child />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Child extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="child">
        <h1>This is a {this.props.foo}</h1>
    </div>
     );
  }
}


export default Parent;
```

Comment: You do not pass the props to the child component, that's why it is undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to transfer the props to `Child`:

```
<Child foo={this.state.foo} />
```

The `state` of `Parent` does not automatically pass to the `Child`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to transfer props to child component:

```
<child foo={this.state.foo} />
```

where you can only read props in child component

Answer (score 1):

Ok If you want to access `foo` in child component as props then you need to pass this.state.foo in child component like this

```
<Child foo = {this.state.foo}  />
```

So change this in your code

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      foo: 'test'
     };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">{this.state.foo}</h1>
        </header>
      <Child foo = {this.state.foo}  />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Child extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="child">
        <h1>This is a {this.props.foo}</h1>
    </div>
     );
  }
}


export default Parent;
```